# How to pass values to shell script executed using the SSH.NET library in C#?

Tags: c#, shell, ssh, ssh.net

Is it possible to use the SSH.NET library to run a script that is saved on the device, that I would make the SSH connection with?

My script would need me to input some variables. Is that also possible through the C# code?

My code here lets me connect to the device and run commands. I just don't know how to make it so that I can interact with the script.

```
// Execute a (SHELL) Command - prepare upload directory
using (var sshclient = new SshClient(ConnNfo))
{
    sshclient.Connect();
    using (var cmd = sshclient.CreateCommand("cd /data/scripts/ && sh funk1.sh"))
    {
        cmd.Execute();
        Console.WriteLine("Command>" + cmd.CommandText);
        Console.WriteLine("Return Value = {0}", cmd.ExitStatus);
    }
    sshclient.Disconnect();
}
```